# R - Discard/Keep elements in a list if children elements exist

Tags: r, purrr

I want to keep all the elements of a list where the children contain a certain named element. For example, in this I only want the elements that contain the child "phone" (elements, 1, 3 and 5).

```
my_list <- list(list(phone = "123-124-1234",
          school = "Midvale"),
     list(address = "123 Main Street",
          color = "blue"),
     list(phone = "124345654"),
     list(color = "green"),
     list(color = "red",
          phone = "12453466"))
```

Using the `purrr` package is ideal for me. Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606433/r-extracting-elements-from-a-list-according-to-a-condition-in-purrr) question.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list %>%
  keep(., ~"phone" %in% names(.))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R we can use `Filter` :

```
Filter(function(x) 'phone' %in% names(x), my_list)

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$phone
#[1] "123-124-1234"

#[[1]]$school
#[1] "Midvale"


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$phone
#[1] "124345654"


#[[3]]
#[[3]]$color
#[1] "red"

#[[3]]$phone
#[1] "12453466"
```